# jQuery validate + AJAX e-mail availiability check

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

**UPDATED**
I'm using jQuery validate plugin and remote method to check email availiability with ajax, but I don't understand why ajax calls only once. When email is entered ajax makes call and in console prints email that is entered, but if i delete it and write in another email nothing happens.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="on0" value="Your e-mail" class="form-field no-mr check-email">
```

jQuery

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('defaultInvalid', function(value, element) {
    return !(element.value == element.defaultValue);
}, 'Custom Error Message for this field');

$('.checkout-form').validate({
    rules: {
        on0 : 'required defaultInvalid email'
    }
});

$('.check-email').rules("add", {
    "remote" : {
        url: 'c/',
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            check: function() {
                return $('.check-email').val();
            }
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
});
```

PHP where ajax makes post

```
<?php 

echo $_POST['check'];

 ?>
```

Comment: What exactly is your reason for adding the `remote` rule separately, when you could just declare it with all the other rules inside `validate()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the reason why ajax fires only once is that you have overwritten the success callback of jQuery validate's remote method. Keep it simple and try something like this:

```
<input name="email_address"/>
```

with script

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('form').validate({
        rules: {
            email_address: {
                required:true,
                remote: {
                    url: "your_script.php"
                }
            }
        },
        debug: true,
        submitHandler: function () { alert('ok'); }
    });


});
</script>
```

and php like

```
<?php 

echo $_GET['email_address'] == "bob";

 ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.checkout-form').validate({
            rules: {
                on0 : {
                    required : true,
                    remote : {
                        url: YOUR_HOST,
                        type: "post",
                        data: {
                            email_address: function()
                            {
                                return $("#email_address").val();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
            messages : {
                required:"message",
                remote: "message"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**in html**

```
<input type="text" name="on0" value="Your e-mail" class="form-field no-mr check-email" id="email_address"/>
```

**And in php code**

```
<?php 

echo $_POST['email_address'];

 ?>
```

Comment: Unless `"required"` and `"remote"` are the `name`'s of `input` elements, the declarations for your `rules:` and `messages:` are all messed up.