# Jquery Validation Ajax doesnt revalidate

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I found this other link
[jQuery validate + AJAX e-mail availiability check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214696/jquery-validate-ajax-e-mail-availiability-check)

The asker shows them wanting to perform some stuff on success but then that field will not revalidate after you change your value and tab out again.

User Dr Blowhard says its because they are overwriting the success callback of the remote method. But he does not give an example on how to handle that. Instead he has a SubmitHandler tied to the validation options. So how do I do a couple of things and then return true or false? For example, if I find the email address, I return some data I already have on file and disable those form fields.

```
$("#userForm").validate({
onfocusout: function (element) {
    this.element(element);
},
onkeyup: false,
rules: {
    email: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        remote: {
            url: 'ajax/checkEmail.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                email: function() {
                    return $('#email').val();
                }
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.status == 1) {
                    $('#affcode').val(data.affCode).attr("disabled", true);
                    $('#userID').val(data.userID);
                    $('#password, #password2').attr("disabled", true);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    $('#password, #password2, #affcode').removeAttr("disabled");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    },
messages: {
    affcode: {
        required: "Please enter a custom affiliate code.",
        regx: "Affiliate codes must start with a LETTER."
    }
}
});
```

My PHP is like this:

```
$res = PDOWrapper::instance()->select('accounts', array("email" => $_REQUEST['email']));

if(count($res) > 0) {
    $return['status'] = 1;
    $return['affCode'] = $res[0]['affCode'];
    $return['userID'] = $res[0]['aKey'];
} else {
    $return['status'] = 0;
}


echo json_encode($return);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to create a custom rule. It is VERY important to add the **var response;** just before the **addMethod**. You only have to declare this once.

```
var response;
$.validator.addMethod(
    "checkAffiliate", 
    function(value, element) {          
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/checkAffiliate.php",
            data: {
                    email: function() {
                        return $('#email').val();
                    },
                        affcode: function() {
                        return $('#affcode').val();
                    },
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data.status == 0) {
                    response = false;
                } else {
                    //Do some stuff here
                    response = true;
                }          
            },
            async: false
        });
        return response;
    },
    "Affiliate Code is already in use."
);
```